# How do I close a window from PeopleCode?

Tags: javascript, java, peoplesoft

As far as I have been able to tell, no one has asked this question on a forum (StackOverflow or elsewhere).

## My Problem

Here is what I need to do. At the hiring offices, they have a computer that is used solely to take I9's from people. This happens very frequently. At the very end, we want to be able to close the browsing window, because then the cache, cookies (and login information) is removed from the I9 Kiosk.

Is there a way to close the current browser window inside of PeopleCode?

## What I have tried

I know that closing a window is trivial in JavaScript. You simply put `window.close()` and the browser window closes. If I could do this in PeopleCode, my problem would be solved. I haven't found any way to do it.
Currently, upon submitting the form the following code is called.

```
%Response.RedirectURL(GenerateScriptContentURL(%Portal, %Node, Record.WEBLIB_G_I9, Field.ISCRIPT1, "FieldFormula", "IScript_I9_CLOSE_KIOSK"));
```

Inside this FieldFormula, the following code happens:

```
%Response.Write(GetHTMLText(HTML.G_CLOSE_FORM_KIOSK));
```

Here is the contents of the HTML being referenced.

```
You have successfully completed Section 1 of the Form I-9. Now present your documentation to the employment representative to complete Section 2

<script language="javascript">
 window.close();
</script>
```

The `window.close();` is not called, and the page only displays the plain text. Is there something I am doing wrong?

I have tried to route to a page with only an HTML area on it, and embed JavaScript in that HTML, but that doesn't appear to work. I have placed this page in the same component as the I9 form, and tried to call `TransferPage(Page.Y_CLOSE_WINDOW);` But this appears to have no affect. This is because of the way that the pages are loaded.

My next thought was to create a JavaObject in PeopleCode which calls JavaScript (using either Rhino, Nashorn, or javax.script.ScriptEngine), but it is rather complicated, and would make me have to introduce a lot of extra code and jars just to run a simple JavaScript command. I would really prefer not to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It is only allowed to close a window by `window.close()` that was  previously opened by `windows.open()`. I think this is the reason why it doesn't work.

I.E. your browser prevents it. If there exists a hack in some browsers to get around this, it's a security bug. e.g. `window.top.close()` works on IE, but not on Firefox.

Do you realy want to close the window without Peoplesoft logout? To logout from current session you can use

```
GetLevel0()(1).CS_SESSION_WK.HTMLAREA.Value = 
  GetHTMLText(HTML.CS_SESSION_LOGOUT, %Request.LogoutURL);
```

With HTML Object like

```
<!% *** Logout Session *** -->
<script language="JavaScript">
    var timer = null
    function move() {
        window.location = '%BIND(:1)'
    }

    timer=setTimeout('move()',2000)
</script>
```

Comment: All the browsers on the Kiosk computers are set to clear cache and cookies when they are closed. So, while logging out in addition to closing would be great, I didn't think that was possible.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to close the main browser window by javascript, nor is it possible to clear cache and cookies automaticaly. Why is it necessary to clear cache and cookies? For security reasons?

Comment: I know you can't clear cache and cookies via JavaScript, but it is possible through all the browsers we use (mostly Chrome/Firefox) when the browser is closed. I'll look for additional info. By the way, I am able to cause the computer to log out by calling `%Response.Redirect(%Request.LogoutURL));`

Comment: Maybe it is a solution for you to kill the browser session by a periodically running script at operating system level, e.g. in Windows `taskkill /fi "windowtitle PS Logout - Mozilla Firefox"` kills the firefox browser with the window title "PS Logout - Mozilla". Window title can be set by java script.